# Há como adicionar comentários de coluna no mesmo comando que create table do Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Há como adicionar comentários de coluna no mesmo comando que o  create table do oracle, assim como é possivel no MySQL?

```
CREATE TABLE user (
   id number COMMENT 'unique ID '
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vc faz isso após o create table.

Não é possível colocar comentários no mesmo comando do create table.

```
-- cria tabela
CREATE TABLE user (
   id number 
);
-- adiciona comentario
comment on column user.id
  is 'unique ID';
```

[Documentação Comment](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4009.htm)

[Documentação Create](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm)